# Solve nonlinear, forced and damped Duffing oscillator

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I solve Duffing equation with Van Der Paul's method:

\begin{align}
\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x + 2 \gamma \dot{x} + \beta x^3 = f \cos(\Omega t)  
\end{align}

with $$x(t) = Re[A(t) \exp(i \omega_0 t)]$$ and $$A(t) = a(t) \exp(i \phi(t)),$$ where $a(t), \phi(t)$ are slowly changing variables. So, I have got this system of differential equations:

\begin{align}
\dot{a} + \gamma a = \dfrac{f}{2 \omega_0} \sin(\Psi), \\
\dot{\Psi} = \delta + \dfrac{3 \beta a^2}{8 \omega_0} - \dfrac{f}{2 \omega_0 a} \cos(\Psi),
\end{align}

where $\gamma, \delta = \Omega - \omega_0 \ll 1, \beta, \omega_0$ are parameters. Can I solve this somehow? I need to get equation of motion $x(t)$ with defined initial conditions.

Without 'force' it's easy to integrate the system and find $a(t), \Psi(t)$.
But I need to take 'force' into account. And I can square both equations to get rid of sine and cosine.

Comment: Is $f$ also a small parameter? What about the size of $β$ or the initial conditions? Essentially, the question is if one treats this as perturbation of the unforced equation or of the linear parts of the equation (or both).